# Porqué no inserta en la BD? my.cnf mal configurado?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, ubuntu, vps

Acabo de instalar entorno LAMP (Mysql 5.7, ubuntu 16.04, php7.0 y apache) en un VPS  administrado con Webmin/virtualmin. Se migró una web instalada en hosting compartido al VPS, antes funcionaban con todas las aplicaciones.
En el sitio web hay un formulario integrado  para insertar campos y fotos.

PROBLEMA: No inserta los registros ni las rutas en la BD, en cambio lo hace guardando las imágenes fisicas en el servidor
Tambien funciona con INSERT desde el terminal Linux. La conexión funciona. El problema debe venir del formulario en sí o alguna configuración de MYsql?

INTENTOS que No lo han arreglado:

- Reinstalar Mysql: sudo apt-get install mysql-server
- Comprobando la conexión:  telnet 127.0.0.1 3306 -->
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to 127.0.0.1
- MY.CNF:  blind-address = localhost ( antes 127.0.0.1)
- instalando PDO: sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
- Desactivando Firewall UFW: sudo ufw disable
- Cambiando el socket mysqld.sock de lugar como aqui se sugiere: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run
- Reiniciando apache y mysql: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart  y 
                sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Es la primer vez que configuro el archivo my.cnf, que venía vacio por defecto con lo cual tuve que añadir algunos parámetros. Lo dejo aqui abajo, junto el formulario  Tiene algun error? 
 No sé ya como resolverlo y quizás debe ser una tonteria.  Cualquier aportación será agradecida.

MY.CNF

```
[client]

socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

bind-address = localhost

port        = 3306

[mysqld]

wait_timeout =600

connect_timeout=600

max_allowed_packet=32M
```

FORMULARIO.PHP

```html
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

if(!empty($_POST)){
$nombre = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['apellido']);

$sql= mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')");
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
       
<div style="float:left;" class="form-group"><br/>
<label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
<div  class="col-md-9">Nombre:
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  required >
</div></div>
            
<div style="float:left;" class="form-group"><br/>
<label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
<div  class="col-md-9">Apellido:
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" >
</div></div>  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

CONEXION.PHP

```html
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mi usuario', 'mi contraseña', 'noombre bd');
 
 if($mysqli->connect_error){
  
  die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);
  
 }
        
 $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
       
?>
```

Comment: Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errar se humano, se te paso un parentesis, te dejo la solucion.

```
introducir el código aquí <?php

                            $server = "localhost";
                            $user = "root";
                            $pass = "";
                            $bd = "db";



                         //Creamos la conexión
                       $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 

                       or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la 
                       conexion de la base de datos");



                    if(!empty($_POST)){
                    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];



                 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (NOMBRES, APELLIDOS) 
                 VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')";//aca habia doble )



                 mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

              if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Nuevo Registro OK";
               } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
                    }
               }
          ?>

          <html>
          <body>

       <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal"
       role="form" action="<?php 
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

            <div style="float:left;" class="form-group"><br/>
         <label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
       <div  class="col-md-9">Nombre:
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  required >
       </div></div>

     <div style="float:left;" class="form-group"><br/>
    <label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
    <div  class="col-md-9">Apellido:
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
      name="apellido" >
       </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
       id="guardar">
             <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Guardar
       </button>

       </div>       
         </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Disculpa lo desordenado pero creo que se entiende xd.
 Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Creo que ese paréntesis doble que corriges estaba bien, ya que  es el cierre de mysqli_query ...  $sql= mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')");

Comment: Alguna solución?

Comment: Intenta con el codigo que puse arriba

Comment: Me funciona bien ese codigo para insertar, si no te funciona te recomiendo volver a instalar LAMP